# extracting watermark svd matlab

Tags: matlab, watermark, extract, svd

I have a problem extracting watermark using SVD.

Here is my code:

```
clc
close all;
a=0.0010
I=imread('citra.jpg'); %Image Host
I=rgb2gray(I);
II=im2double(I);
[U,S,V]=svd(II);
M=imread('logoUPN.jpg'); %Image Watermark
M=rgb2gray(M)
W=im2double(M);
%Embedding St = S + a * W;
AW = U * St * V';
imwrite(AW,'watermarked.jpg');
%Extract IW =imread('watermarked.jpg'); WW = im2double(IW);
ST=U' * WW * V;
Ww=(ST-Siga)/a;
figure,imshow(AW);
figure,imshow(Ww);
```

Extracting image is blurry and not clear. I want to make two menu embedding and extraction.

Answer (score 0):

For extracting watermark use [UT ST VT] = svd(WW) instead of ST=U' * WW * V and then use this ST value to extract watermark.

Answer (score 0):

Here S is an diagonal matrix and other two are the respective left and right singular vectors which follows the rule U*S*V'.
To get the S value we can't apply the reverse multiplication. So need to write            [U S V]=SVD(WW) in place of expression.